# How to query on same table to fetch the data based on status

Tags: postgresql, jpa

In our application there is a report which shows how may points he/she transferred to other persons, as of now we are fetching with status "Transferred" but sometimes these points can be rejected by other person or sender.

When transfer happens a row will be inserted in DB with status called "Transferred" and if the other persons receive or reject either case another row will be inserted status will update accordingly.

Now I want to fetch in my reports only transactions that have successfully transferred and received, it should not fetch the transactions which transferred but rejected
Transaction id will be same for Transfer, receive and rejected, to identify what action performed on transfer

```
 id  trans_id Amount  from  to  createdOn                 status
1234    1234  1000     abc  xys 2017-07-10 15:00:00       Transfer
1235    1234  1000     abc  xys 2017-07-10 15:10:00       Rejected
1236    1246  100      xyz  abc 2017-07-11 01:00:00       Transfer
1235    1236  100      xyz  abc 2017-07-11 01:10:00       Received
```

I want to query to fetch as requested

Comment: Did you try something and it didn't work?

Comment: JPA is based around classes/fields not tables. Define your entities and relations

Comment: @GabiM, no I didn't get any solution, as of now I pulling all records which create confusion whether the amount transferred or rejected.

Comment: @NeilStockton I know how to work with JPA, if I've Query which can give results as I expected, I will use the same query in JPA with @Query()...

Comment: To define a query, people need to see the damn entities. Don't post them if you like but you won't get an answer either. Your choice.